# Problems with Auth0 loginWithRedirect() - stuck on callback after login | Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, authentication, auth0

I got a problem with my vue application with Auth0.

I implemented auth0 inside my vue3 application according to the provided manual:
https://developer.auth0.com/resources/guides/spa/vue/basic-authentication

I used as well the appState.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <q-btn
      label="Login"
      @click="login()"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

    return {
      login: () => {
        loginWithRedirect({
          appState: { target: "/app/test" },
        });
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I am redirected to the authentication page (auth0) and can successfully login and be redirected to my callback page.

The problem is - that's it. I don't get redirected to "/app/test" or "/". I am still at the /callback page.

According to the manual - I should be redirected to "/" if I don't have the appState set. I tried both - I always get stuck on the callback page.

No errors or whatever - user is also successfully logged in.

I know - I could cheat with a redirect on the callback page with router.push(), but that's not what I want - I want to pass some url parameters from the login page.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I've read your question and seems unclear to me. What is your actual problem? Provide code and give details. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for reaching out!

I the desired redirection to "/app/test" or "/" is not executed. I just get to my /callback page.

Comment: Did you set the VITE_AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL env variable to point you on /app/test?

Comment: no, in my auth0 config is the normal /callback page. According to the docs ==>

"By setting up the value of appState.target to /profile, you are telling the Auth0 Vue SDK the following: When my users log in with Auth0 and return to my Vue.js application, take them from the default callback URL path, /callback, to the "Profile" page, /profile. If you don't specify this appState.target option, your users will be redirected by default to the / path after they log in."
https://developer.auth0.com/resources/guides/spa/vue/basic-authentication#add-user-login-to-vue-js

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - it happened to be a problem with quasar and auth0-vue

For anybody who's interested, check out the issue on GitHub

https://github.com/auth0/auth0-vue/issues/255